# Is there a way I can display bootstrap popover content in a loop?

Tags: c#, html, twitter-bootstrap, razor, popover

My popover content seems to always display the first item in the list. How can I get it to display each individual item?

Here is the Razor HTML I am using

```
    @{
    
       foreach(item in Model.SomeObject)
       {
         <div class="popover-loop" data-toggle="popover" data-popover-content=".popoverContent">i</div>
       }
            
    
       <div class="hidden popoverContent">

          <div class="popover-heading">
             <h4>This is Heading</h4>
          </div>
    
          <div class="popover-body">
             <p>@item</p>             
          </div>
       </div> 
    }
```

And here is the JS

```
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
                html: true,
                content: function () {
                    var content = $(this).attr("data-popover-content");
                    return $(content).children(".popover-body").html();
                },
                title: function () {
                    var title = $(this).attr("data-popover-content");
                    return $(title).children(".popover-heading").html();
                }
            });
        });
    
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a crude solution which is to change the popoverContent class to an ID and append a count keeping track of the loop.

So essentially the popoverContent will be popoverContent_@count where count is a variable in the loop.

I am sure there is a better solution though so if anyone has other suggestions?